# Play Framework 2.3 - Strange behaviour accessing server externally

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

I have a Play app running in development, I was thinking that I would forward the 9000 port on my router to my development PC so that I could share the app with a few friends to ask for some input.

After forwarding the ports I was able to access the app using my external IP and port 9000. However after ~5 mins Play's server (just using the default one, Netty I think) started timing out and I was unable to get a response... I was still able to access the server normally locally (both using localhost and accessing through the router, but not externally to my home network).

I have checked my firewall and the router's firewall and there doesn't seem to be a problem. I can bind a different app to the port and it stays open and communicating.

If I restart the Play application then it is able to communicate for a further ~5 mins before beginning to fail again.

Is there any issues with Play that might somehow be able to prevent this? I'm so confused as the app runs locally as expected but I cannot see and firewall/router problems so I am left assuming that it MUST be the Play app (but that makes no sense right???)

I start the server using:

`activator -jvm-debug 9999 run`

... that I call from a batch file. I'm on windows 7.

Comment: That only happens in dev mode?

Comment: FWIW -> I had(once) a problem with a WiFi router that was blocking(or somethin') port 9000 even without an active firewall. Got it working by changing to a more "standard" port like 443.

Comment: I tried port 80 and still the same issue, it works until it is left idle for ~5 mins. Also I have thus far been unable to deploy the app in anything other than dev mode as I am running into other (unrelated?) issues, so I cannot say if it is only in dev mode.

Comment: I'll be getting a linux machine to deploy it on, hopefully this wall make a difference.